# How to sample n pixels from different object classes in tensorflow?

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, image-segmentation, sampling

### Problem

I want to randomly sample `n` pixels from every instance class in an image.

Lets say my image is given as `I` with width `w` and height `h`. I also have an image with the labels `L` describing the instance classes of the same shape as `I`.

### Current Approach

My current idea is to first reshape the labels to one large vector of shape `(N_p, 1)`. Then I repeat them `N_c` times to have shape `(N_p, N_c)`. Now I repeat a vector `l` consisting of all unique labels with shape `(1, N_c)` to shape `(N_p, N_c)`. Equaling those two gets me a matrix with a one in column `y` and row `x`, where pixel corresponding to row `x` is of class corresponding to column `y`.

The next step is to concatenate a matrix with increasing index positions with the previous matrix. Now I can random shuffle that matrix across the rows.

The only missing step is to extract `n*N_c` rows of that matrix, which first have a one for each of the classes. Then using the indices in the right part of the matrix, I can use

```
tf.gather_nd
```

to get the pixels out of the original image `I`.

### Questions

1. How can I achieve the missing operation in tensorflow? That is: Get the k*n rows, such that they contain each the first n rows having a one in the left part of the matrix for each column of the matrix.
2. Are these operations efficient?
3. Is there some simpler method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

For anybody interested, here is the solution to my problem with corresponding tensorflow code. I was on the right track, the missing function is

```
tf.nn.top_k
```

Here is some example code to sample k pixels from each of an image's instance classes.

```
import tensorflow as tf

seed = 42

width = 10
height = 6
embedding_dim = 3

sample_size = 2

image = tf.random_normal([height, width, embedding_dim], mean=0, stddev=4, seed=seed)
labels = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=tf.uint8)


labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int32)

# First reshape to one vector
image_v = tf.reshape(image, [-1, embedding_dim])
labels_v = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])

# Get classes
classes, indices = tf.unique(labels_v)

# Dimensions
N_c = tf.shape(classes)[0]
N_p = tf.shape(labels_v)[0]

# Helper matrices
I = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(indices, [-1]), [1, N_c])
C = tf.tile(tf.transpose(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(N_c), [-1])), [N_p, 1])
E = tf.cast(tf.equal(I, C), tf.int32)
P = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(N_p) + 1, [-1])
R = tf.concat([E, P], axis=1)
R_rand = tf.random_shuffle(R, seed = seed)
E_rand, P_rand = tf.split(R_rand, [N_c, 1], axis = 1)
M = tf.transpose(E_rand)
_, topInidices = tf.nn.top_k(M, k = sample_size)
topInidicesFlat = tf.expand_dims(tf.reshape(topInidices, [-1]), [-1])
sampleIndices = tf.gather_nd(P_rand, topInidicesFlat)
samples = tf.gather_nd(image_v, sampleIndices)

sess = tf.Session()
list = [image,
        labels,
        image_v,
        labels_v,
        classes,
        indices,
        N_c,
        N_p,
        I,
        C,
        E,
        P,
        R,
        R_rand,
        E_rand,
        P_rand,
        M,
        topInidices,
        topInidicesFlat,
        sampleIndices,
        samples
        ]
list_ = sess.run(list)
print(list_)
```